# Kubuntu 21.10 - Laptop suspends on first login after reboot

Tags: kubuntu, suspend, lenovo, 21.10

I've had a weird behavior since around Kubuntu 20.04 which has persisted to 21.10. What happens is that after I've rebooted the laptop, unlocked the encrypted drive and have entered the login credentials, the laptop immediately suspends. I've got the laptop lid closed and a USB-C USB-hub connected to my keyboard and mouse. I also have external monitors connected through the USB-C ports. The laptop can be resumed by using the keyboard and further suspends work fine, until the next reboot. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need to edit your `Power.conf` file and change a `false` to a `true`. Here's how:

0. Open a terminal window
1. Edit the `Power.conf` file as the super user:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/UPower/Upower.conf
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Feel free to use any text editor. It does not need to be `vi`.</sup>
2. Look for `IgnoreLid=false`. This will be somewhere around line 39.
3. Change `false` to `true`
4. Save the file and exit (<kbd>Esc</kbd>⇢<kbd>W</kbd>⇢<kbd>Q</kbd> if using `vi`)
5. Reboot and test

This should do what you need

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. Still getting the same behavior.